# Evaluate $ \int \int_{S} F \cdot n \ dA \ $ by Gauss-divergence theorem

Tags: calculus, vectors

Evaluate $ \int \int_{S} F \cdot n \ dA \ $ by Gauss-divergence theorem , where

$ F=[x,y,z] \ \ and \ \ S: x^2+y^2+z^2 =9 \ $. Use parametric equations of sphere also to verify.

**Answer:**

$ Div (F)=3 \ $

Thus  by divergence theorem ,

$ \int \int_{S} F \cdot n \ dA \\ =\iiint_V div(F) dV=3 \iint_V dV =3 \times volumes \ \ of \ \ sphere \ S=3 \times \frac{4}{3}\pi (3^3)=108 \pi \ $

Is it true ?

Now  to verify  $ \int \int_{S} F \cdot n \ dA  =108 \pi \ $  using parametric equations ,

let $ x= 3 \cos \theta \cos \phi , \\ y=a \cos \theta \sin \phi, \\ z=a \sin \theta \ $

**Now how do I find  $ n dA \ $ ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By direct computation we have

$$\oint_S \vec F\cdot\hat n\,dS=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\pi \left.\left(\vec r\cdot \hat r r^2 \right)\right|_{r=3}\sin(\theta)\,d\theta\,d\phi=4\pi (3)^3=108\pi$$

And using the Divergence Theorem, we have

$$\oint_S \vec F\cdot\hat n\,dS=\int_V \nabla \cdot \vec F\,dV=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\pi\int_0^3 (3)\,r^2\,\sin(\theta)\,dr\,d\theta\,d\phi=108\pi$$

as expected!

Comment: How do you do in the direct computation using parametric equations ?  Particularly how did you find $ \ n dA \ $ ?   would you show me a little work more ? Thank you

Comment: The unit normal to the sphere is the radial unit vector $\hat r$.  The position vector $\vec r=\hat xx+\hat yy+\hat zz=\hat rr$ in spherical coordinates.  And the differential surface element $dS=r^2\sin(\theta)\,d\theta\,d\phi$ in spherical coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is true. for computing $RHS$ find $\vec{n}$ by finding gradient of the surface then $\vec{n} = \frac{(x,y,z)}{3}$

$F.\vec{n} = \frac {x^2+y^2+z^2}{3} = 3$ so now it can be computed easily